# Windows Server 2019 RRAS lab can't make NAT and routing work together

Tags: windows, routing, nat, rras

I setup a lab, but i can't make it work.

The lab is:

[network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJWHP.png)

I can access the internet via 10.0.0.254.

- If i configure RRAS with static routing, i can access the other network. But i can't access the internet.
- If I add NAT configuration on both servers, i'am able to get access to internet, but i'm no longer able to ping between local network.

Do you see a solution to make it work with the current network configuration?

Thanks

Comment: *Ping between networks* precludes NAT. Just use basic routing. Internet access requires a default route to WAN (and NAT for IPv4).

Comment: it's working via basic routing. IT just doesn't work anymore if i activate nat on both site to get access to internet.

Comment: NAT what is destined for the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only activate NAT for the WAN-facing interface (that your diagram doesn't show), not for the routing between private subnets.

Each router requires two (static) routes, one for the non-local subnet (for 192.168.0/24 on Router 2 and for 192.168.10.0/24 on Router 1), and one default route for 0.0.0.0/0 towards the Internet. Of course, an additional, invisible WAN router would require back routes for all the subnets behind your RRAS subnets, non-local to the WAN router.

Comment: Thanks. As i am not able to configure the invisible WAN router, i found other solutions :
- VPN between local network.
- Add another network card on 10.0.0.0/24 on both router. Use NAT on one, and just routing on the other one